# CSS animate border in and out

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following css to animate a border on hover:

```
.item {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
  background: orange; 
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.item:hover {
  border: 8px solid green;
}
```

It works on hover but when I move the mouse out, the border disappears without an animation. Is it possible to slide the border out as well?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rwgZXp

Comment: Just use `box-sizing:border-box` in your `.item` class

Comment: this doesn't fix the lack of animation on mouse out - at least not in chrome anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can resolve the issue by animating only `border-width`

**See result:**

```css
.item {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
  background: orange;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  border: 0px solid green;
}

.item:hover {
  border-width: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```

Comment: to prevent apply annimatyion to all properties , you I think its better to set annimation only for the border-width like  `transition: border-width .5s ease-in-out;`

Answer (score 4):

Add transparent border on `.item` and change color on hover.

```
.item {
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
.item:hover {
  border-color: green;
}
```

Also note the use of `background-clip` property. This will limit background color only to the content area excluding borders.

```css
.item {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
  background: orange; 
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  background-clip: content-box;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.item:hover {
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In order for an animation to work, the value you are animating must have a defined amount to animate from and to.

As you never initially set a value for border, the animation has nothing to animate back to when your mouse leaves the element.

The fix for this is to set the initial border to `border:0 solid green;`. The hover animation will then smoothly animate from 0 to 8px on hover and smoothly back down to 0 on mouseleave.

[Example here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRJBPb)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a transparent border to the div initially. Then animate the colour. In order to preserve the width and height of the div add `box-sizing: border-box`...

```css
.item {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
  background: orange;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.item:hover {
  border: 8px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily add a `border: 0px solid green;` for `.item`.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal this happens because you haven't added a border. The border comes only with hover effect. So when you took the mouse pointer out browser doesn't know whether there was a border or not. So you have to add a border with 0px size as mentioned below.

```
.item {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
  border: 0px solid green;
  background: orange; 
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.item:hover {
  border: 8px solid green;
}
```

I hope this would give you what you want exactly.